# Custom HTML - SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am trying to write out custom HTML in an SSRS report.  If I try to put the html in a placeholder (selecting Markup type = "HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles"), SSRS will strip out any unsupported tags.  Therefore, I am trying to write it out in custom code.  My expression is as follows:

```
=Code.WriteHTML("<b>ryantest</b>")
```

My custom code is as follows:

```
Function WriteHTML(ByVal Msg As String) As String
If Not (IsNothing(System.Web.HttpContext.Current)) Then
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Msg)
End If
End Function
```

When I try to view the report, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred during client rendering.
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi user - you could try replacing the angle brackets of your unsupported tags with entities e.g. ampersand gt semicolon, and leave out calling the custom code.

Comment: Yes, that will work for the <b> tag, but I want to use more complicated (unsupported) tags.  My main goal is to output an interactive bing map (so I will need <script> tags, which SSRS doesn't support (it strips them out)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with Microsoft.  Their rendering engine has no way of supporting custom HTML.  The only approach is to inject the HTML after SSRS is done processing the report or write your own rendering extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you've added a reference to that assembly to the report, otherwise it would probably throw some other error.

What about permissions? You need to do something funky to call outside assemblies from SSRS custom code.

PS: I've never seen anyone call that assembly from custom code. Cool hack.

Comment: I've added a reference to System.Web.  I've also updated the policy config file to give full trust (I was getting a different error with that.